# output not showing as per wanted

Tags: c

I am beginner to C language and I am writing a code for mathematical operations.
The code that i have written so far is as follows but does not ask the user for second number input.

```
int main()
{
    int num_1 = 0;
    int num_2 = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int Total = 0;

    printf("\nEnter 1 for add:\n ");
    printf("Enter 2 for subtract:\n ");
    printf("Enter 3 for division:\n ");
    printf("Enter 4 for multiplication:\n ");
    printf("Enter 5 for percentage:\n ");
    printf("Enter 6 for power:\n ");
    scanf("%d", n);

    printf("Enter first number:  ");
    scanf("%d", num_1);
    printf("Enter second number:  ");
    scanf("%d", num_2);







    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Adding to @xing comment, and `n` as well.

Comment: Your program probably crashes because `n` is zero, and gets treated as a null pointer (or an otherwise invalid pointer) and when `scanf()` tries to write via the invalid pointer, the program probably crashes instead of continuing.  Use `if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) { …report error and exit… }`, where the `&` is crucial.

Answer (score 5):

Use '&' in scanf for n, num1 and num2.
Scanf("%d", &n);

Comment: Thanks it really did work. going forward i am almost done with my code but it gives me an error after the "switch" statement. The code is as follows: